# Writing to Firebase Storage directly fails sometimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am writing to a pdf file in Firebase storage. I am using the following code.

```
      const myPdfFile = myBucket.file('/' + fileName);          
      var stream = myPdfFile.createWriteStream();

      stream.write(sr);

      stream.on('finish', function () {
        if (debug) console.log("Finished Writing");
      });

      stream.on('error', function (e) {
        if (debug) console.log("There was an error" + e);
      });

      stream.end('End\n');
```

This code runs successfully most of the time. Sometimes it fails and does not even trigger 'error'. I also see that the stream did not trigger 'finish' for those writes. Could someone please help?

Comment: What are you seeing on [cloud monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/monitor-storage#stackdriver_monitoring)? Allow, Deny, Error?
When if fails do you simply run again the script or it always fails with certain types of files or situations?

Comment: Cloud monitoring shows Allow. When it fails, I run the script again and it succeeds. I am actually testing bulk creation. I run about 100 file creations. 1 or two of them fail. All of them have the same content.

Comment: So I've been looking for similar issues, but I'm not sure if the behavior you're seeing is intended. Firebase Storage is not a file system. You can only Write, Delete and Read. No update, no move. So while it might be possible I don't think this is intended usage.